# Using parameters as fixture arguments without indirect=True

Tags: pytest

I have some fixtures that I would like to parametrize, but I would like to use these parameter values within the body of a test function as well. Here is a simple example:

```
def add_numbers(x, y):
    """Function to test."""
    return x + y


@pytest.fixture
def expected_sum(x, y):
    """Useful fixture for the test."""
    return x + y


# TODO: parametrize x, y for several different values
def test_add_numbers(expected_sum, x, y):
    """Both the test body and the fixture depend on x and y."""
    assert add_numbers(x, y) == expected_sum
```

I know that the usual way of parametrizing fixtures is to use `@parametrize` with `indrect=True`, but I'm not sure if I can re-use those parameter values within the test itself.

I have found that I can directly parametrize the test arguments, and somehow these values are forwarded to the arguments of the fixture:

```
def add_numbers(x, y):
    return x + y


@pytest.fixture
def expected_sum(x, y):
    print('expected_sum called with', x, y)
    return x + y


@pytest.mark.parametrize('x', [1, 2])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('y', [3, 4])
def test_add_numbers(expected_sum, x, y):
    assert add_numbers(x, y) == expected_sum
```

As expected, this results in the output

```
test_main.py::test_add_numbers[3-1] expected_sum called with 1 3
PASSED
test_main.py::test_add_numbers[3-2] expected_sum called with 2 3
PASSED
test_main.py::test_add_numbers[4-1] expected_sum called with 1 4
PASSED
test_main.py::test_add_numbers[4-2] expected_sum called with 2 4
PASSED
```

Is this documented behavior of pytest? What is actually happening under the hood to make this "cleaner" indirect parametrization work? (E.g., does `@parametrize` create fixtures for `x` and `y` that both `expected_sum` and `test_add_numbers` are able to use?)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you need, is using [expected_sum as a factory](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#factories-as-fixtures)
This way, you can do as follows:

```
def add_numbers(x, y):
    return x + y


@pytest.fixture
def expected_sum(x, y):
    def _expected_sum(x, y):
        return x + y
    return _expected_sum


@pytest.mark.parametrize('x', [1, 2])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('y', [3, 4])
def test_add_numbers(expected_sum, x, y):
    assert add_numbers(x, y) == expected_sum(x, y)
```

To your last question, I don't have the answer :(

Comment: Thanks Joaquin, this looks like a reasonable solution! I am still curious why the simpler approach seemed to work without needing to create a factory or deal with indirect parametrization.